# Getting text outside element but next to Elements using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

```
<tr class="s">
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 100px"></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <a target="_blank" href="" title="Localiser avec Google Maps">
            <img src="images/gm.gif?v=7" alt="Google Maps" class="gm noauto" align="right">
        </a>
        10, rue Edmond Rostand - 13006 MARSEILLE
        <br>
        <strong>Tél :</strong> 04.33.54.03.09<br>                           
        <strong>Fax :</strong> 04.11.54.29.85<br>                           
        <strong>Email :</strong> <a href="mailto:wsedrftg.tgtg.rftg@gmail.com" class="icone email">wsedrftg.tgtg.rftg@gmail.com</a><br>                                                     
        <strong>Début d'activité :</strong> 10/06/2013<br>                          
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to extract email, phone, name and date from the code above. I have managed to get name and email address, though I am stuck.

I also want to get phone, date, and fax which seems to be outside elements.

```
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines)
{
    Elements trs = headline.select("tr.t");
    Elements phnDiv = headline.select("tr.s td:eq(1)");

    for (int l = 0; l < trs.size(); l++)
    {
        j++;
        Elements name = trs.get(l).select("th");
        Elements emailAddress = phnDiv.get(l).select("a");
        Elements phone = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Tél :)");
        Elements faxx = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Fax :)");
        //Elements debutdactivite = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Début d'activité :)");

        String contactName = name.text();
        String email = emailAddress.text();
        String tel = phone.text().replace("Tél :", "");
        String fax = faxx.text().replace("Fax :", "");
        //String date = debutdactivite.text();

        System.out.println(j + " Name : " + contactName + " Email : " + email + " Phone : " + tel + " Fax : " + fax );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get those values by using the `nextSibling()` method. It returns a `Node` so you don't have to worry about the values being inside an element.

Once you grab the elements you want, the code would look like this:

```
String tel = phone.nextSibling().toString();
String fax = faxx.nextSibling().toString();
```

This will grab the Node directly next to the phone and faxx elements that have been selected.

Comment: phone and fax is of type elements and that method (nextSibling()) is not found.

Comment: @webscrapingtech if there are multiple Elements, I would think you would want to loop through them to get the values for each... otherwise just get the one Element (i.e. one phone and fax) that is next to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `jsoup` to directy get the parts you want, since they're not Elements ...

What you could do is get the `html()` of the `<th>`-Element and then use a regular expression to get phone, fax and date with a regex like this

```
"<.*Fax.*> (.*?)<br>"
```

Should work like this

```
    @Test
    public void test() {

    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<.*?Fax.*?> (.*?)<br>");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher("<strong>Tel :</strong> 04.11.55.29.85<br>    <strong>Fax :</strong> 04.11.55.29.85<br>");
    m.matches();
    assertEquals("04.11.54.29.85", m.group(1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {

                Elements trs = headline.select("tr.t");
                Elements phnDiv = headline.select("tr.s td:eq(1)");

                for (int l = 0; l < trs.size(); l++) {

                    j++;
                    Elements name = trs.get(l).select("th");
                    Elements emailAddress = phnDiv.get(l).select("a");
                    Elements phone = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Tél :)");
                    Elements faxx = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Fax :)");
//                    Elements debutdactivite = phnDiv.get(l).select("strong:contains(Début d'activité :)");

                    for (Element nnjnj : phone) {
                        String ph = nnjnj.nextSibling().toString();


                        for (Element fxx : faxx) {
                            String fx = fxx.nextSibling().toString();

                            String contactName = name.text();
                        String email = emailAddress.text();

//                    String date = debutdactivite.text();

                        System.out.println(j + " Name : " + contactName + " Email : " + email + " Phone : " + ph + " Fax : " + fx);

                        }

                    }
                }


            }
```

Now after i run this i get all the results thanks @Justin for bringing light on this.